# is there a php code that include/require a page and not a file? (PHP)

Tags: php

I have a page 'Error 404' and the address is like http://myurl.com/error404

the php file of error404 require's the index.php to properly show it.
I need a php code that will load or show the content in the url above without redirecting/changing the url. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo file_get_contents("http://myurl.com/error404");
```

Works also for URLs.

[DOCS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)